# Importing declarations from multiple objects at once

Tags: scala, class, object, import

I have multiple objects containing `case class` declarations. For example:

```
object model1{
   //case classes
}

object model2{
   //case classes
}

object model3{
   //case classses
}
```

Importing each of those `model`s separately is cumbersome. Is it possible to import it at once somehow?

The following **does not** work

```
object all{
    import model1._
    import model2._
    import model3._
}

import all._
```

Maybe some macro can be useful here?

Comment: AFAIK no in Scala 2, Scala 3 will provide an `export` feature wich will make this possible.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you could take a look at all definitions in each of these objects, and generate code, that basically delegates `implicit`, `val`, `def`, `type` to definition in original object, but that would be:

1. slow, because macros,
2. not supported by IDEs, because macros.

If you are on Scala 2.13 you can try using something like [`-Yimports`](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6764) to configure global imports, if you use imports very often - it should be supported by newest [IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16562).

On Scala 3 you will have [export](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/export.html) as mentioned by @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez.